# SELECT COUNT in WHERE CLAUSE in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I know that something similar was here some time ago,but it wasn't the same case and I can't just figure it out on myself.
I need to transform raw SQL query to Eloquent.

This query contains SELECT COUNT in WHERE clause, for simplicity I have this (may has not much sense) query :

```
SELECT u.column1, u.column2, u.column3, s.column1 FROM users u
LEFT JOIN salary s ON u.id = s.user_id  
WHERE 
(
SELECT count(cars_id) FROM cars WHERE cars.user_id = u.id
) = 0 
AND u.city IN ("London","Paris")
```

I tried:

```
$columns = [
        'users.column1',
        'users.column2',
        'users.column3',
        'salary.column1'
        ];

$q = User::select($columns)
    ->leftJoin('salary', 'salary.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->whereRaw(" (SELECT COUNT(cars_id) FROM cars WHERE cars.user_id = u.id) = 0 ")
    ->whereRaw("u.city IN ('London','Paris')") 
    ->get();
```

But it doesn't return same results as raw SQL (SQL had 161 rows and Eloquent 154 rows).

Maybe you know how to transform this kind of query correctly to Eloquent?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your  query I believe this should do it:

```
DB::table('users as u')
    ->select([ 'u.column1', 'u.column2', 'u.column3', 's.column1'])
    ->leftJoin('salary as s', 'u.id', '=', 's.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('cars as c', 'c.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
    ->whereIn('u.city', ['London', 'Paris'])
    ->havingRaw('count(c.id) = 0')
    ->get();
```

Please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for answer,I will try in the evening and let you know, as I have to adjust your idea to my SQL query I have to transform. But looks promising.